# Strange outcome when I don't output an specific variable

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program in order to get 5 numbers from the user and output the second largest number.

As you can see, I call a function to search for the max, then I set every equal amount to -999 to omit them in the next search, and finally we search again for the maximum number between remaining numbers. That would be the second largest number.

*The problem is, if I don't output the "maximum" variable ( I called it "the first max" ) , then the final output is zero! no matter what the inputs are!*

I don't know why and how these are connected, but here we are!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <conio.h>

int searching (int arrays [])
{
   int max = 0;

    for ( int i ; i < 5 ; i++ )
        if ( arrays [i] > max )
            max = arrays [i] ;

return max;
}

int main ()  {

   int maximum;

   int numbers [5];

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )                              
        cin >> numbers [i];

    maximum = searching (numbers);  

    cout << "First max : " << maximum << endl;

    for ( int i ; i < 5 ; i++ )                                 
       if ( maximum == numbers [i] )
          numbers [i] = -999 ;


     cout <<  "Second max : " << searching (numbers);

     getch();
     return 0;

}
```

now if I omit the following line, the final answer would be zero :|

```
cout << "First max : " << maximum << endl;
```

So confusing :|

( note: and I also appreciate any better idea about how to reform the code, Thanks anyway for reading. )

Comment: Leaving the algorithm aside, you did not initialize `i` in `for`.

Comment: @ZDF: Please do not write answers in the comment section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this twice:

```
for ( int i ; i < 5 ; i++ )
//    ^^^^^
```

Your `i` is uninitialised. It may not start at 0. Consequently you could easily be reading from / writing to array elements that don't exist.

That gives your program *undefined behaviour* — you violated the contracts of the language, and the compiler's activities — both in terms of it performing optimisations using the contract defined by the language, and in terms of just general compilation procedure — have caused what you perceive to be a strange pattern of behaviour.

In general, that sort of pattern — input magically changing based on whether or not you have a `std::cout` in a certain place — almost *always* indicates undefined behaviour. When you see it, check that you're not overflowing a buffer somewhere or reading an uninitialised variable (which includes verifying that you don't have failing user input without any error checking).

Comment: I can't believe I made such an stupid mistake :)) Thanks a lot man. You bought me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to implement this is to keep track of **two** values: the largest seen so far, and the second largest seen so far. As you go through the loop, if `arrays[i]` is greater than `max`, copy `max` to `second_largest`, and copy `arrays[i]` to `max`; otherwise, if `arrays[i]` is greater than `second_largest`, copy `arrays[i]` to `second_largest`.

Comment: That seems to be an awesome idea. Thanks.